# iOS: Best practice for recreating addTarget() in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrol

I'm creating a custom `UIControl` subclass, and want to add a `addTarget()` function, similar to UIButton. How do I do this properly? So far I have this (it works, but not sure if is a good solution):

```
import UIKit

class RichLabel: UIControl {

    var labelTarget: Any?
    var labelAction: Selector?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder _: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector) {
        self.labelTarget = target
        self.labelAction = action
    }

    func buttonAction() {

        if let labelTarget = labelTarget, let labelAction = labelAction {               
         let _ = (labelTarget as AnyObject).perform(labelAction, with: self)
    }
}
```

The target is added from another view, like this:

```
var richLabel: RichLabel {
    let label = RichLabel()
    label.setAttributedText(title: string)
    label.addTarget(self, action: #selector(richLabelAction(label:)))
    return label
}
```

Comment: `UIControl` has `func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControlEvents)` available already - why not just use that?  You will just have to choose a `UIControlEvent` that matches the action you need to trigger the `Selector`.

Comment: So I should override that function? Or how do I trigger the selector that is set with the included UIControl addTarget function?

Comment: It totally depends on "who" the target is.  Is this something where the `RichLabel` is going to react and do something when the user interacts with it, or is it something that the containing `UIViewController` needs to know about?

Comment: The target is another view or whatever. It should be used just like a UIButton's addTarget usually is used. Updated my question.

Comment: Check my answer - that will accomplish what I THINK you are asking for.  Exactly the same way I'd handle button taps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inherit from `UIControl`, you don't need to do anything to `addTarget`. Callers will use `addTarget` on your custom UIControl the same way they would any other control. All your custom control has to do is decide when it wants to call those actions, and call `sendActions(for:)`.

If your goal is to have this `RichLabel` class function just like a button, I would add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it, and in the gesture recognizer, call `self.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)`.

```
class RichLabel: UIControl {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelTapped))
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    required init?(coder _: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @objc func labelTapped() {
        // When this happens, any object that called `addTarget`
        // for the .touchUpInside event will get its callback triggered
        sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. :) I might have to add targets for many different events, so I might need to do a custom one, so I can have different/more states than what is provided with `UIControlState`. Do you know how I then best should store the target/selectors? How do UIControl do this internally?

Comment: Storing actions/selectors is an implementation detail of `UIControl` that I don't think we need to know about as developers. Are you sure you can't get by with the values provided by `UIControlState`? Keep in mind, you can pass back the `RichLabel` in the function called by the selector. So if you have a `#selector(labelTapped(_:))`, your function will look like `func labelTapped(_ label: RichLabel)`. So instead of a bunch of different selectors, you could use `label` to get more information about the context.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try to solve it by doing it this way. :)

Comment: This is not true: "All your custom control has to do is decide when it wants to call those actions..". That's not needed and I'd say it's a bad practice. Adding TapGR to UIControl class is unnecessary and sending action from there is confusing.
Who would expect that UIControl's TouchUpInside event is called right away? There is no chance to cancel the touch (via TouchUpOutside) etc.

Answer (score 3):

Since `UIControl` already gives you access to `func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControlEvents)` you can just use that.  For example, if you have the label added to a `UIViewController`, and want that viewController to be able to react to something like `editingDidBegin` you could add this code to your viewController:

```
@IBOutletWeak var richLabel: RichLabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.richLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(labelEditingDidBegin(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin)
}

@objc func labelEditingDidBegin(_ sender: RichLabel) {
    print(sender.text)
}
```

I'm not sure if your `RichLabel` allows editing, etc, but you can observe whichever `UIControlEvent` you need, react to that, and then execute whatever code you need in your `Selector` function.

Comment: @Connor Ah, ok, I didn't understand that from the question.  Nice one - you get an upvote from me.